# Writing a video with H.264 in OpenCV with High profile from a high profile mp4 file

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-capture

I have High profile mp4 video i am using opencv to overlay some text inside but output.mp4 is writing in simple profile format. is there a way to write it in high profile
I am using opencv 3.4.16 latest

Devlopment platform is: Windows C++ VS2019

> VideoWriter videocc(destFile, VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'P', '4', 'V'), fps, cv::Size(width, height));

I have tried X264 , H264 ,AVC1 in fourcc, But not writing in high profile

Is there a way or sample available to generate high profile output video format

please find the following attachment for main profile coded problem

[image]

Comment: Still cant able to achive the high profile output from opencv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to pass parameters through OpenCV, to ffmpeg and libx264.

As far as I can tell from official documentation, OpenCV doesn't support that.

**However**, the source contains access to the environment variable [`OPENCV_FFMPEG_WRITER_OPTIONS`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/97c6ec6d49cb78321eafe6fa220ff80ebdc5e2f4/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp#L2727)

You *should* be able to pass parameters like you would give them to ffmpeg, except the syntax is a little weird (semicolon between key and value, pipe between pairs).

Here is some talk of such facilities:

- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6342
- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9292

You should pass `avc1` as fourcc. AFAIK that's the fourcc defined by standards. It does not however guarantee that you get libx264, only that you get some encoder for AVC.

I've opened [an issue for this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21155). Documentation issues are always a nice way for newbies to get their feet wet contributing to an open source project.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using AVC1 as the fourCC code (as suggested by Rackwitz) and also set the environment variable:

```
export OPENCV_FFMPEG_WRITER_OPTIONS="vcodec;x264|vprofile;high|vlevel;4.0"
```

To verify that the H264 codec and high profile was used, I checked using
[ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html)

It worked prefectly.

- OS Ubuntu 18.04
- OpenCV 3.4.14
- FFMPEG 3.4.8